# How do I remove the abbreviation which appear on methods and variables in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: The red arrows marks the abbreviations]

I have tried and googled without finding the way to remove the abbreviations.
I'm also new to IntelliJ.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: do you mean something like replacing the text `ctrl + shift + r` ?

Comment: If you look at the picture the red arrow explain the abbreviation. For example the val(see picture) is an abbreviation for String or double/int etc..

Comment: I need to click on "val, {...}" to see the datatype or method.

Answer (score 5):

You have installed [Advanced Java Folding](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9320-advanced-java-folding) plug-in which does exactly what you see, folds and abbreviates certain language constructions.

Either uninstall/disable the plug-in or configure its options according to you personal preferences:

[image: advanced folding]

Comment: I uninstalled it, but the abbreviations is still in my code.

Comment: Maby I should re-install IntelliJ.. :)

Comment: Check other Folding settings, like to fold one-line methods, etc. [Disable them all](http://i.imgur.com/eW3Null.png) if you don't need any folding.

Comment: A little late reply, but I worked it out. Thanks for helping me :)